# About d3.js: How can i make the csv support chinese data?

Tags: csv, d3.js

How can I make the d3.csv to support chinese?

Answer (score 0):

D3 should support any character set, or rather be oblivious to it. If you're having problems, this is most likely caused by your browser. Check your browser settings and the [character encoding](http://www.webstandards.org/learn/articles/askw3c/dec2002/) of the page you're loading.